# Font size for Name and Description PDF Digital signature

Tags: java, itext7

If I use font size `appearance.setLayer2FontSize(6.0f);` it sets font size for both Name and Description.

[image]

```
        PdfReader reader = null;
    PdfSigner signer = null;
    try {
        reader = new PdfReader(inStream);
        signer = new PdfSigner(reader, pdfos, false);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error while loading PDF");
        throw new DigitalSignException("Error while loading PDF", e);
    }

    int noOfPages = signer.getDocument().getNumberOfPages();
    PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance().setReason(reason).setLocation(loc)
            .setReuseAppearance(false);
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(250, 100, 200, 80);
    appearance.setRenderingMode(RenderingMode.NAME_AND_DESCRIPTION);
    appearance.setLayer2FontSize(6.0f);
    appearance.setPageRect(rect).setPageNumber(noOfPages);
    signer.setFieldName("sign");

    // Creating the signature
    IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(pk, digestAlgorithm, bouncyCastleProvider.getName());
    IExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    try {
        signer.signDetached(digest, pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, subfilter);
    } catch (IOException | GeneralSecurityException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error while adding digital signature to PDF");
        throw new DigitalSignException("Error while adding digital signature to PDF", e);
    }
```

Is there a way to set different font sizes for Name and description
 (Name should be little bigger than description)

Answer (score 3):

The whole `Layer2Text` is a single `String`, whether you set it or iText builds it, and it is typeset as a single paragraph using a single font and font size. Thus, NO, you cannot ask iText to draw your `Layer2Text` or its default text using multiple styles for different parts of it.

What you can do, though, is to retrieve the `PdfFormXObject` `Layer2` before iText has created its appearance on it, and you can draw anything in any style on it.

So, instead of

```
appearance.setRenderingMode(RenderingMode.NAME_AND_DESCRIPTION);
appearance.setLayer2FontSize(6.0f);
appearance.setPageRect(rect).setPageNumber(noOfPages);
```

you'd do

```
appearance.setPageRect(rect).setPageNumber(noOfPages);
PdfFormXObject layer2 = getLayer2();
[...shape the layer2 contents as you desire...]
```

Of course you can use the source of the `PdfSignatureAppearance` method `getAppearance` for inspiration, in particular if you don't want your design to deviate much from the default.

Thus, YES, you can completely customize the signature appearance.

#### For example

An example customized layer2 content might be shaped like this:

```
PdfFormXObject layer2 = appearance.getLayer2();
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(layer2, signer.getDocument());

float MARGIN = 2;
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont();

String name = null;
CertificateInfo.X500Name x500name = CertificateInfo.getSubjectFields((X509Certificate)chain[0]);
if (x500name != null) {
    name = x500name.getField("CN");
    if (name == null)
        name = x500name.getField("E");
}
if (name == null)
    name = "";

Rectangle dataRect = new Rectangle(rect.getWidth() / 2 + MARGIN / 2, MARGIN, rect.getWidth() / 2 - MARGIN, rect.getHeight() - 2 * MARGIN);
Rectangle signatureRect = new Rectangle(MARGIN, MARGIN, rect.getWidth() / 2 - 2 * MARGIN, rect.getHeight() - 2 * MARGIN);

try (Canvas layoutCanvas = new Canvas(canvas, signer.getDocument(), signatureRect);) {
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(name).setFont(font).setMargin(0).setMultipliedLeading(0.9f).setFontSize(20);
    layoutCanvas.add(paragraph);
}

try (Canvas layoutCanvas = new Canvas(canvas, signer.getDocument(), dataRect);) {
    Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph().setFont(font).setMargin(0).setMultipliedLeading(0.9f);
    paragraph.add(new Text("Digitally signed by ").setFontSize(6));
    paragraph.add(new Text(name + '\n').setFontSize(9));
    paragraph.add(new Text("Date: " + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss z").format(signer.getSignDate().getTime()) + '\n').setFontSize(6));
    paragraph.add(new Text("Reason: " + appearance.getReason() + '\n').setFontSize(6));
    paragraph.add(new Text("Location: " + appearance.getLocation()).setFontSize(6));
    layoutCanvas.add(paragraph);
}
```

This essentially is a copy&paste&refactoring of the iText code creating its default appearance with different font sizes for different text parts of it.

Comment: thanks for the response, I am not finding the way. Could you share some code if you have.

Comment: Some of the ways I tried:- PdfFormXObject layer2 = appearance.getLayer2();PdfStream pdfStream= layer2.getPdfObject();
  com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfIndirectReference ref = pdfStream.getIndirectReference();
  com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfObject pdfObject = ref.getRefersTo(); 
  PdfName key = new PdfName("Type");
  pdfObject =pdfStream.get(key);

Comment: For your task you should have taken the original iText code for inspiration. I've added an example doing so.