# Is it possible to configure where IText PdfSignatureApperance Layer2Text is shown

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, itext7

The following code adds a signature to a pdf document and also sets the visual appearance using iText7.

```
public static byte[] SingPdfViaCertificate(X509Certificate2 cert2, byte[] pdfToSign)
    {
        var apk = Org.BouncyCastle.Security.DotNetUtilities.GetKeyPair(cert2.PrivateKey).Private;

        IExternalSignature pks = new PrivateKeySignature(apk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA512);

        var cp = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser();
        var chain = new[] { cp.ReadCertificate(cert2.RawData) };

        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(pdfToSign)))
        {
            using (MemoryStream fout = new MemoryStream())
            {
                StampingProperties sp = new StampingProperties();
                sp.UseAppendMode();

                PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, fout, sp);
                PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.GetSignatureAppearance();

                appearance.SetPageNumber(1);
                appearance.SetLayer2Text("Hello world");
                appearance.SetLayer2FontSize(8);

                ImageData imageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\test\Desktop\images.jpg"));
                appearance.SetImage(imageData);
                appearance.SetImageScale(1);

                Rectangle pr = new Rectangle(10, 10, 200, 100);
                appearance.SetPageRect(pr);

                appearance.SetRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION);
                appearance.SetPageRect(pr);

                signer.SignDetached(pks, chain, null, null, null, 0, PdfSigner.CryptoStandard.CMS);
                return fout.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

The appearance consists of a background image and some text. 
[image]

I'd like to have the text starting at the left bottom corner: 
[image]

Is is possible configure the location where the layer2text is shown in the appearance?

Comment: You can retrieve the whole "Layer" 2 (`getLayer`) and put any content onto it wherever you want.

Comment: You might be interested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49009766/1729265) which is similar to yours, merely for iText 7 for Java instead of .Net.

Comment: I've already found it and i currently try to get it working. The different rectangles/margins seem to be complicated and i was only able to show the text using trial/error. Besides this, when using this approach, the SetImage doesn't work anymore, but i assume this then must also be solved via canvas. But it seems the way to go. Thanks and cheers

Comment: *"Besides this, when using this approach, the SetImage doesn't work anymore, but i assume this then must also be solved via canvas."* - Indeed. *"using trial/error"* - consider looking at the iText code in question for creating the default appearance, it's the method `GetAppearance` in `PdfSignatureAppearance` in the `if (app[2] == null)` block.